# Geting dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable from a .deb built by me

Tags: python, debian, dpkg

I'm tryng to transform my python3 program in a .deb program using `dpkg -b <myprog>`, but every time that I try to install the .deb file, dpkg returns this:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

My  program's tree:

```
prog_v1.0.0
├── DEBIAN
│   └── control
└── usr
    ├── bin
    │   └── progname<principal script>
    └── share
        └── progname<files that are used>
            ├── help.txt
            └── others
                ├── cl.txt
                └── l.csv
```

and this is my control file:

```
Package: my_program_name
Version: 1.0.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: <my name> <my e-mail>
Depends: python (>= 3.7), python3-mplfinance , python3-tk, python3-pandas
Installed-Size: in_kb
Description: <my description>
```

Other informations:

```
OS: Debian 11
Python version:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```